# Rendering HTML local file with out browser or networking (lightweight)

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I have had a lot of trouble trying to find information or possible examples of this being done.

I would like to render html in a window and take the js from the html and output that to a python code.

The Html is local and there will never be an internet connection for it to run off. Everythin i try shearch for possible answers everyone always seems to relate back to using some small lightweigh browser which in my case isn't an option to use.

Fort some more detail, I am running Selenium-Webdriver
(python) and Iceweasel(Raspberry Pi B+) to get the value of a element from a html page. So using a different browser isnt possible as the lightweight ones are not compatible with selenium. Using Selenium and Iceweasel takes in excess of 2 miunets to fully load up which for what i need it for is far to long.

I had a look into Awesomium but i think it lacks compatability with the Raspberry Pi.
My other thought was to use OpenGL to render the html but found no easy explained examples.

Currently looking into LibRocket, Berkelium and QWebView but again i dont think they will have anythin i need with the compatability i need.

**EDIT:**

Basically i want  a Canvas capeable of rendering HTML to a screen using X11. On the HTML there will be buttons. I want those buttons to preform actions inside a python script.

The way i see it, a browser is basically a toolbar, a canvas and a lot of networking. I want to strip away as much of that as possible and just remain with the canvas.

Comment: Do you actually also need to run that javascript? If not, you can get content of any url using library like [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). And then parse it with [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: I'm unsure, I basically have a bunch of buttons. each button runs a js to set the value of an element to something, Selenum then takes that element value and uses it in a python script. If there is a way of checking button events (on click) then that would negate the use of javascript.

Comment: btw. selenium also support [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) maybe that will be your way.

Comment: as far as i know phantomjs is headless. i actually need the display more than i need the js.

Comment: Now I don't understand what you are doing :) Do you need just interact with some page programmatically or you also need to watch that in the process ?

Comment: i need a html page full of buttons that i can press using a touch screen, i need a python code to see which buttons i pressed. Each button will have a value and python needs to get that value to do something with. Using a browser just kills the Pi

Answer (score 0):

First go to the directory that you has the local webpage.  Than run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`.  This will "render the html" in a window.  Then view source and paste the javascript into a python file.  Alternatively if you would like to automate piping the javascript into an out file you can use [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to select the javascript and write it to any file you want.  Then manipulate it in python however you want.

Comment: I dont think this is what im looking for. Like i said before im not looking to make a server then use a browser to view it. and i also have to see and interact with the rendered html. this just makes a local server for a browser to connect to.

Comment: @AceScottie sorry I misunderstood.  So you want to render html in a browser?

Comment: not exactly. i want to render html in an openGL canvas (or something like it) and then output the events to a python script. so the HTML will be rendered on screen (using X11 and xinit) then the buttons on the HTML will be output to a python code (so if button 1 is pressed etc.)